# Rewriting adress with a dot - "/." in htccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite (301) `https://www.myadress.com/.` to `https://www.myadress.com/` How can I do it? The web browser seems to doesn't see the dot after slash.

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^\.$ https://www.myadress.com/ [L,R=301]
```

But the code above is not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts in your question(keep it up). Could you please do let us know if you want to remove anything comes after `https://www.myadress.com/` eg--> `https://www.myadress.com/singh_blabla` you want to remove it and make it to `https://www.myadress.com/`? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: Also one more thing url `https://www.myadress.com/` is being served by any index.php etc file in backend? Kindly confirm that once too.

Comment: yes, I want to remove anything after "/" (in this case anything means the dot) and rewrite to `https://myadress.com/` because `https://www.myadress.com/.` returns error 404.

Comment: How are you getting a single dot in a URL after `https://www.myadress.com/`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shown samples could you please try following. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. These rules will remove any uri present in url and redirect it to base domain url as per your shown samples.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$ 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST} [R=301,L]
```